# Recursive SQL Query: One entry ponting to another, and traversing it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL query (for SQl Server), and am curious if there is a simple method to achieve my ends. I will simplify things to get to the heart of the matter:

I have a table with two columns, which we can call column A and column B. Column A contains the name of a segmented file, and column B contains the next part of the segmented file. So, I can have multiple segments pointing to multiple segments.

So, for example:

```
Column A     Column B
File 1       File 2
File 2       File 3
File 3       File 4
File 7       File 13
```

I need to get a list of all the segments starting with File 1 and ending with File 4, preferably in one column. Or, to put it another way, I need to start with a given entry in column A, and having something traverse and dereference entries from column B, until no entry can be found from column B in column A.

Something like SELECT allsegments() From FTable WHERE FTable.A = "File 1"?  Or do you think I need to write some custom code?

Comment: What exactly should be output for your example? It's not clear to me what condition connects columns A and B.

Comment: Output should be a single column with the following entries (assuming I feed it File 1) -> File 1, File 2, File 3, File 4. It does not progress from File 4 because an entry for File 4 is not found in Column A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a recursive CTE it can look something like this:

```
declare @T table
(
  ColumnA varchar(10),
  ColumnB varchar(10)
);

insert into @T values  
('File 1',       'File 2'),
('File 2',       'File 3'),
('File 3',       'File 4'),
('File 7',       'File 13');

with C as
(
  select T.ColumnA,
         T.ColumnB,
         cast(T.ColumnA+','+T.ColumnB as varchar(max)) as Comb
  from @T as T
  where T.ColumnA = 'File 1'
  union all
  select T.ColumnA,
         T.ColumnB,
         C.Comb+','+T.ColumnB 
  from @T as T
    inner join C
      on T.ColumnA = C.ColumnB
)
select top 1 Comb
from C
order by len(Comb) desc
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Result:

```
Comb
------------------------
File 1,File 2,File 3,File 4
```

Default `maxrecursion` is 100 so if you have more than 100 files in a chain you need to specify the number of allowed recursions. `option (maxrecursion 0)` makes the max number unlimited.

Comment: Interesting. Just for my own information, how expensive do you think this query is? As in, do you think it would be wiser to structure my tables another way, or running this query on several thousand records isn't a worry?

Comment: @user978122 I think performance will be good. You need to have an index on `ColummnA`. With `ColumnB` included or the index on `ColumnA` as clustered to avoid a table scan.

Answer (score 0):

```
select path from 
(
   select connect_by_isleaf leaf, sys_connect_by_path(von, '/') path
     from table1
    start with A = 'File x'
  connect by   A = prior B
) where path like '%File y';
```

=> This query returns the possible paths from File x to File y, seperated by / or any
delimiter of your choice.